# How can change textsize of menu item?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

My project include navigation drawer in menu folder of the values named `drawer.xml`. Items of this menu has icon and title. The font size of items are normal for all screens. But, I must increase font size and I should change icon size for `sw600dp layout`.

I tried solution that I found from stackOverflow. I added the code below to `style.xml` in `values-sw600dp`and I increased icon size in `drawable-sw600dp`. But that all didn't work.
  `<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    </style>`

drawer.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <menu 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <group

      android:id="@+id/group_member"
      android:checkableBehavior="single">
      <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sign_in"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
        app:theme="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
        android:title="@string/menu_user_settings" />
      </group>
      <group
      android:id="@+id/group_information"
      android:checkableBehavior="single">
      <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_registered_users_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_registered_user_list" />
      <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_rate_us" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_about_us" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_phone_in_talk_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_contact" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the theme for every element, set the theme to your `Navigationview`. Like,

```
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
</style>
```

to `Navigationview`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    android:theme="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
     />
```

Comment: I added this before `<group` starting. But it don't work. I added to wrong place? I should change menu tag that is top of the code?

Comment: **Element android support.design.widget.navigationView is not allowed here**. It show this error. Where I should add the code you written?

Comment: Where you have added the `DrawerLayout`

Comment: Ok. I solved this problem. Edit your answer and add android:theme instead of android:itemTextAppearance. This solved my problem.